# Allow Period in Rules Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, rule

Here is my Rule

**Old Rule**

```
    'DriverName' => 'required|unique:driver|alpha',
```

I tried to convert my Rule to allow DriverName to allow `.` (Period) But It shows invalid format

What is the Mistake i am doing in the Rule

**New Rule Re-Written** (Error)

```
    'DriverName' =>  array('required', 'unique:driver','regex:/^(.)$/'));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `.` is a special character in regex; it should be escaped like this: `\.`

The rule should the be like this `'regex:/^\.$/'`

Note that this accepts a `.` only, nothing else.

If you want to accept any combination of alphanumerics and `.` then you should have something like this:

```
'regex:/^[\w.]+$/'
```

Comment: I mean how the rule should be  ?

Answer (score 0):

Just change your Rule to

```
'regex:/^(.)$/'
```

to

```
'regex:/^./'
```

So Your New Rule would be

```
'DriverName' =>  array('required', 'unique:driver','regex:/^./'),
```

Comment: Can i Give my input like **A.John** or **John A.** or **John.A** like that ?